# How to delete values in json-jquery-array?

Tags: jquery

my php file returned a json array full of values.

```
$positions = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($abfrage)){
array_push( $positions, array('posID' => $row['posID'],'pos1' => $row['pos1'], 'pos2' => $row['pos2']));        

}

@mysql_close($connection);
echo json_encode(array("positions" => $positions));
exit;
```

Now in my js-File i want to delete a data set where posID == x for example,
but i dont how to do it

```
$.each(positions, function(i, v){
   if(v.posID == id){
 ... delete data set ...
}
});
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new array with the items that you want to keep:

```
var result = $.grep(positions, function(v){
  return v.posID != id;
});
```